orphanRemoval, preRemove event and Soft Delete doesn't work (Doctrine, Symfony)
When my entity is an orphan and fires the preRemove event I want to fill in a "deleted by" field:
#[AsDoctrineListener(event: Events::preRemove, priority: 500, connection: 'default')]
...
 /**
     * Set Deleted By and Deleted At values
     *
     * @param PreRemoveEventArgs $args
     * @return void
     */
    public function preRemove(PreRemoveEventArgs $args): void
    {

            $entity = $args->getObject();

            /**
             * @var User $user
             */
            $user = $this->security->getUser();

            $entity->setDeletedBy($user->getId());
            $entity->setDeletedAt(new DateTimeImmutable());
            // Here it shows deletedBy with the correct user id
            // dd($entity);
    }

If I dump it I can see it is filled in, but after it is flushed and in the DB that column is blank.
This is the same for postRemove and the only way I could get this to work was if I manually handled each orphaned item individually in a loop outside of events, as this event fires for every entity and works as expected I am hoping I can use it or make something similar for the orphan entities.
Is there any solution to this?

Am I missing something or you're updating the entity that's gonna be removed?
PS.: This seems like a kind of "domain" requisite so I would not implement it in an infrastracture component (like a listener is). I would create a use case you should always use to remove the child entities and not let doctrine handle it for you.

@DonCallisto, yes since it is only soft deleted I am wanting to add the Deleted By (User ID). My main goal was to keep everything as inline as possible, every entity will have these fields and will need them populated so was hoping to handle it all in one space. Otherwise I cannot see anyway around this other than manually handling the deletion individually. But I also can't help but feel this a bug on the side of Doctrine.. or I am not understanding how "orphanRemoval" works.
